# Get login shell of a user not in /etc/passwd in linux

Tags: linux, shell, etcpasswd

How do I get the default login shell of a specific user in linux. The user isn't necessarily in `/etc/passwd`. They may be logging in with NIS or LDAP or other pam method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ getent passwd "${username}" | awk -F: '$0=$7'
```

If the user exists both locally and e.g. in LDAP this will return multiple entries so you will need to decide on one line being returned.